# Blk update request: I/O error . Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, acpi

When booting Ubuntu, my laptop is first displaying a message "ACPI probe failed"
then it starts throwing "Blk update request: I/O error" (see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ngc7ilgpkfU))

Is this the HDD failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run *badblocks* and that is showing me I have indeed some bad blocks on the HDD